# Sybase Stored procedure returned Multi ResultSet

Tags: java, stored-procedures, sybase, jdbctemplate

I have a problem, I using jdbcTemplate exec a Sybase stored procedure returning mulit ResultSet,how could I get all the resultSet?

```
if object_id('p_if_pms_spyh_upload') <> null 
    drop proc p_if_pms_spyh_upload
go
create procedure p_if_pms_spyh_upload
@status          char(1)                ---  订单状态  A/D
as
begin

    declare @rq char(8) , @errcode int, @errmsg varchar(60)     

    create table #head (
        op_type   char(2) not null,                     -- 操作类型 A 表示新建  D 表示删除
        xyqrid   varchar(30) not null,                --  确认函编号
        dh        varchar(20) not null,                -- 优惠单编号 
        yhdmc   varchar(30) not null,               -- 优惠单名称
        type      varchar(18) not null,                -- 直降种类  04表示10有函              
        qsrq     char(8) not null,                           --  起始日期
        jzrq         char(8) not null,                          -- 截止日期 
        qssj     char(8) not null,                      -- 起始时间 
        jzsj      char(8) not null,                             -- 截止时间
        jsfs      varchar(8) not null,                      ---结算方式
        oano    varchar(30) not null,                   -- OA公文号
        description   varchar(200)  not null,      -- 优惠单描述
        oprrq   char(8) not null,             -- 审批删除日期
        oprsj   char(6) not null               -- 审批删除时间    
    )     
    create table #detail (
        op_type   char(2) not null,                     -- 操作类型 A 表示新建  D 表示删除
        xyqrid   varchar(30) not null,                --  确认函编号
        dh        varchar(20) not null,                -- 优惠单编号 
        gdsid    varchar(20) not null,               --  优惠商品名称
        orgid    varchar(10)  not null,               -- 销售组织编码
        qdid     char(4) not null,                      -- 渠道编码
        tjlb        varchar(20)  not null,              -- 商品组
        pp        varchar(20)   not null,              -- 品牌编码
        gys       varchar(20)   not null,              -- 供应商编码
        fmid      varchar(10)   not null,             -- 库位编码
        yhed     numeric(16,4)  not null,            -- 优惠额度
        yhsl      numeric(16,4)   not null,            -- 优惠数量
        unit       varchar(3)  not null                 -- 销售单位
    ) 

    -- 删除1个月之前已成功发送的数据
    select @rq=convert(char(8),dateadd(month,-1,getdate()),112) 
    select @errcode=0
    select @errmsg = ''

    begin tran

        delete from IV_YHD_HEAD_SPYH_TO_PMS where  processflag = 'S' and convert(char(8),lastmodified,112)  = @rq
        if @@transtate = 2 or @@transtate = 3 or @@error != 0        
        begin       
                select @errcode=-1  
            select @errmsg = '删除IV_YHD_HEAD_SPYH_TO_PMS一月之前的数据失败！'                                     
                     goto procfail        
        end  

       delete from IV_YHD_DETAIL_SPYH_TO_PMS where  processflag = 'S' and convert(char(8),lastmodified,112)  = @rq
        if @@transtate = 2 or @@transtate = 3 or @@error != 0        
        begin     
                select @errcode=-1      
           select @errmsg = '删除IV_YHD_DETAIL_SPYH_TO_PMS一月之前的数据失败！'                                     
                     goto procfail        
        end  

        insert into #head 
        select op_type, xyqrid, dh, yhdmc, type, qsrq,jzrq, qssj, jzsj, jsfs, oano, description, oprrq, oprsj
        from IV_YHD_HEAD_SPYH_TO_PMS where processflag = 'Y' and op_type = @status

        update IV_YHD_HEAD_SPYH_TO_PMS set processflag = 'R'
        from IV_YHD_HEAD_SPYH_TO_PMS a, #head b
        where a.dh = b.dh and a.processflag = 'Y' and a.op_type = @status
      if @@transtate = 2 or @@transtate = 3 or @@error != 0        
        begin   
                select @errcode=-1       
           select @errmsg = '更新IV_YHD_HEAD_SPYH_TO_PMS表数据出错！'                                     
                     goto procfail        
        end  

        insert into #detail
        select a.op_type,a.xyqrid,a.dh,a.gdsid,a.orgid,a.qdid,a.tjlb,a.pp,a.gys,a.fmid,a.yhed,a.yhsl,a.unit
        from IV_YHD_DETAIL_SPYH_TO_PMS a,#head b
        where a.dh = b.dh and a.processflag = 'Y' and  a.op_type = @status

        update IV_YHD_DETAIL_SPYH_TO_PMS set processflag = 'R'
        from IV_YHD_DETAIL_SPYH_TO_PMS a, #head b
        where a.dh = b.dh and a.processflag = 'Y' and a.op_type = @status
      if @@transtate = 2 or @@transtate = 3 or @@error != 0        
        begin   
                select @errcode=-1       
           select @errmsg = '更新IV_YHD_DETAIL_SPYH_TO_PMS表数据出错！'                                     
                     goto procfail        
        end  


    procsuccess:
         commit trans
         goto myexit

    procfail:
         rollback trans
         goto myexit

       myexit:
          select  @errcode,@errmsg  
          select  op_type, xyqrid, dh, yhdmc, type, qsrq, jzrq,qssj, jzsj, jsfs, oano, description, oprrq, oprsj from #head
          select op_type,xyqrid,dh,gdsid,orgid,qdid,tjlb,pp,gys,fmid,yhed,yhsl,unit from #detail

end
go
grant all on p_if_pms_spyh_upload to ws
go
```

I got you what you say and try something else. I show you the code blow:

```
                        ResultSet rs = null;
                        int updateCount = -1;
                        int index = 1;

                        do {
                            updateCount = cs.getUpdateCount();
                            if (updateCount != -1) {      // it means it's a updateConut
                                cs.getMoreResults();
                                System.out.println("updateCount:" + updateCount);
                                continue;
                                }

                            rs = cs.getResultSet();
                            System.out.println(rs);
                            if (rs != null) {// it means updateCount == -1 and returns a resultSet

                                if (1 == index) {
                                    index++ ;
                                    if(rs.next()) {
                                        int errCode = rs.getInt(1);
                                        String errMsg = rs.getString(2);
                                        System.out.println("errCode:" + errCode + "    errMsg:" + errMsg);
                                        if (!(Constants.PROC_ERRORCODE_SUCC == errCode)) {
                                            logger.error("call sp errror:" + errMsg);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else if (2 == index) {
                                    index++ ;
                                    rs = cs.getResultSet();
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                         //proc resultSet                                               
                                    }

                                } else if (3 == index) {
                                    index++ ;
                                    rs = cs.getResultSet();
                                      // proc resultSet

                                    }

                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }

                                cs.getMoreResults();
                                continue;
                                                             }
                            // it means updateCount == -1 && rs == null nothing left to return    
                        } while (!(updateCount == -1 && rs == null));
```

this is the debug result

```
updateCount:1
updateCount:1
updateCount:1
updateCount:0
updateCount:0
updateCount:1
updateCount:1
updateCount:1
updateCount:1
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet@bd4e3c
errCode:0    errMsg: 
updateCount:1
updateCount:1
updateCount:1
null
```

This is the correct code

```
                        ResultSet rs = null;
                        int updateCount = -1;
                        int index = 1;

                        do {
                            updateCount = cs.getUpdateCount();
                            if (updateCount != -1) {// it means it returns a updateCount
                                cs.getMoreResults();
                                continue;
                            }

                            rs = cs.getResultSet();
                            if (rs != null) {// it means it returns a ResultSet
                                if (1 == index) {
                                    index++;
                                    if(rs.next()) {
                                        int errCode = rs.getInt(1);
                                        String errMsg = rs.getString(2);
//                                        System.out.println("errCode:" + errCode + "    errMsg:" + errMsg);
                                        if (!(Constants.PROC_ERRORCODE_SUCC == errCode)) {
                                            logger.error("call sp execute error:" + errMsg);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    rs.close();  // it should call close() here 
                                } else if (2 == index) {

                                    index++;
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                          //proc the second resultSet
                                    }
                                    rs.close();     // it should call close() here 
                                } else if (3 == index) {
                                    index++;
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                        //proc the second resultSet                                         
                                    }

                                    rs.close();  // it should call close() here 
                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }

                                cs.getMoreResults();
                                continue;                                 
                            }


                        } while (!(updateCount == -1 && rs == null)); //nothing to return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep calling the getMoreResults in a loop

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
ResultSet rs;
int i;
...
cstmt.execute();                            // Call the stored procedure 

while (cstmt.getMoreResults()){             // If we have more Results

    rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the result set

    while (rs.next()) {                     
        i = rs.getInt(1);                      
        System.out.println("Value from result set = " + i);  

    }
}

rs.close();
cstmt.close();
```

For your stored proc, it looks like you always return the three resultsets

The code should get you close, but if you want to debug it, you can do the loop like I showed you, and inside the loop, call ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData(); and the rsmd object will tell you pretty much everything about that current [resultset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html), this way you can get a true idea of what is being returned.

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
ResultSet rs;
int i;
...
cstmt.execute();                            // Call the stored procedure 

    // select  @errcode,@errmsg

    rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the result set

    while (rs.next()) {                     
        // Process the resultset   

    }

    rs.close();

    // select  op_type, xyqrid, dh, yhdmc, type, qsrq, jzrq,qssj, jzsj, jsfs, oano, description, oprrq, oprsj from #head

    rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the result set

    while (rs.next()) {                     
        // Process the resultset   

    }

    rs.close();

    // select op_type,xyqrid,dh,gdsid,orgid,qdid,tjlb,pp,gys,fmid,yhed,yhsl,unit from #detail

    rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the result set

    while (rs.next()) {                     
        // Process the resultset   

    }

    rs.close();

cstmt.close();
```

Comment: You don't really need the loop, you can call the getMoreResults() if you know you have a fixed set of result sets.

Comment: Thanks first, but some update are in proc, I'm not familiar with sp so I don't know how to do with this,it gives me a headache. I paste the sp ,could ou help me? @Mike

Comment: I got you say and find something online  and paste some new code up@Mike. I debug it and find something confused me .I also show the result of debug up .I think that if the grant command has something to do with ? any idea?

Comment: Hi @Mike, you should call cstmt.getMoreResults() method to next ResultSet, but you remind me to call rs.close(), thank you very much ,I solve this problem which confused me two days.It's very nice of you.I also paste the code up .